# A conflicting transaction has been detected in our memory pool. The transaction hash displayed below may change

Tags: transactions, blockchain, unconfirmed-transactions

SO i received this transaction from my other wallet
1)  https://blockchain.info/tx/06810d392213a7453bbe6ad4ab95c0892875b0db2b56b3db5ef942b0a42eced4
for 1.02BTC

and sent these for 1btc and 0.2btc while the previous transaction was unconfirmed:
2)  https://blockchain.info/tx/44f68a0987fe9dfe88045c977c5d66534a65ca399f0d2b27fec7c80785ddc759
3)  0.2 (similar to 2) )

Now suddenly from my other wallet automatically
 4)  a new transaction for the same value but different hash

and the transaction number 1) shows
 A conflicting transaction has been detected in our memory pool. The transaction hash displayed below may change.

Can you tell me when 1) will be confirmed, and are 2) and 3) dependent on 1).
How long until the transcation is unconfirmed that the bitcoin is refunded.
I have paid the fees for all transcations.
Pls help!

Comment: sounds like some sort of transaction malleability attack

Answer (score 2):

There has been some malleability attacks recently - third party duplicating the transactions.

See https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_Malleability for details on the attack technique.

The attack is merely an annoyance as far as I've understood, and there is a BIP in the making (BIP 62) to deal with this attack vector.

Perhaps this explains your problems.